# How to build pjsip library supporting more than one target Archetecture?

Tags: android, pjsip

I am not able to build a PJSIP library supporting more than one architecture in one app.

As per building library reference I can build for only architecture. E.g.

> TARGET_ABI=arm64-v8a

So how can I build as in below picture

[image]

Comment: Build for arm64-v8a and move it to the arm64-v8a folder manually, Repeat for all architectures you want.

Comment: @user8127814  i had done by building entire library for each and manually copied to JniLibs . but Android app never detect all librararies which are manually copied.. is there anywhere i have to configure for those manually added libraries

Comment: Where did you put the jniLibs folder? mine is at app/src/main/jniLibs